# How to check dependency to a class by other classes

Tags: java

I have a project which has a large number of classes(>1000) which are archived into 7 jars. All these jars are built separately (using ant). If some one has changed one of these classes, there may be numerous other classes that depends on this one, and all those will fail runtime. How can i check the dependency to a class file from other jars?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. There are many ways that an IDE can help you with this issue.

If you don't have the source code or source jars for the projects, you should create some integration tests that can assist you in regression testing (actually, most will say that you should do this anyway). You can start by looking at JUnit. After a change, if any test fails, you know that you will need to look into the usage of the class/API.

Comment: I do not have the source for some jars. Is there any plugin to eclipse or any script that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize something like NetBeans you could have all the projects open and use 'Find Usages'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) tool.

Comment: if i migrate to Maven, will it be helpful

Comment: This is not a Maven tool. It's a standalone java application that allows you to point at a collection of jar files and graph the dependencies between jars, packages and classes.